# emacs - Font ‘Menlo’ is not defined

Tags: osx, fonts

I have installed [emacs26.3 for macosx](https://emacsformacosx.com/), but when I run emacs, below error happen:

```
Font ‘Menlo’ is not defined
```

Then I try to install Menlo font with below command but not helpful

```
brew cask install font-menlo-for-powerline
```

How can I install Menlo font for macosx?

Comment: Why/how is this a question about Emacs? Are you able to install the font for use outside Emacs? What does Emacs have to do with it?

Comment: Thanks, it should be a macosx issue and I have submitted a report to macosx forum as well. but I wish emacs experts maybe help me as well.

Comment: What is that you want to know, from Emacs experts?

Comment: `font-menlo-for-powerline` is a font named `Menlo for Powerline`. It is not named `Menlo`. The bigger mystery is: do you have Menlo? It should be included on every Mac OS X system. Try running the Font Book app to see if it's in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```sh
brew cask install homebrew/cask-fonts/font-menlo-for-powerline
```